# Need xpath for my specific dom element to identify that element (selenium web driver)

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am in to test automation using selenium. I want to identify element using Xpath

Its HTML structure is like this:

```
<p class="ng-binding">
<span class="ng-binding">Patrik</span>
Thomson
</p>
```

I want to build Xpath, which can identify this entire element using First Name & Last Name.

There could be 2 Pattern of Xpath, below are examples
Pattern 1: `/x:html/x:body/x:div[1]/x:div/x:div/x:div`

Pattern 2: `/ul/li[@class='ng-scope'][@title='For']`

I want to identify my element using pattern 2 where I search using FirstName & Last Name.

Comment: Any one help how to show the html structure as well in my post. Currently my post does not show html structure.

Comment: Can you add the html over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below xpath

```
"//p[contains(.,'Thomson')]/span[text()='Patrik']"
```

After locating the element using firstName & lastName , you can traverse forward, backward using function available in xpath based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
//p[@class='ng-binding'][normalize-space() = 'Patrik Thomson']
```

The `normalize-space()` takes the *string value* of the element you're testing (which means the concatenation of all descendant text nodes with the intervening tags removed), strips leading and trailing whitespace and normalizes internal runs of whitespace to a single space character.